# Issue with Interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.dll

Tags: sql, interop, ssis, bulkloader, comexception

I converted an old dts package into SSIS package and trying to run it Windows 2008 server. This SSIS package runs an Win32 exe file which is using **Interop.SQLXMLBULKLOADLib.dll** and trying to load some XML data into database. But i get following error when this exe gets executed.

**COM Exception: Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {8270CB2F-B0E6-4C37-8A40-D70778F47894} failed due to the following error: 80040154.**

I'm trying to run the .exe file in Windows 2000 compatability mode. Please let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That CLSID belongs to SQLXML 3.0. You can [download 3.0 sp3 here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=11811). FYI 0x80040154 = REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG.

As far as I can tell SQLXML 4 does not implement the same CLSID, so I think you'll actually have to install 3 even if you have 4 installed already.

Comment: Thanks. I will install SQLXML 3 and  re-run the package amd let you know.